# regex does not remove non digits from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string "item number:237728"
I'm applying replace

```
str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
```

but the string does not change, non digits are not removed. any idea why? 
thanks

Answer (score 10):

Are you assigning the returned value and using that,  e.g. `str = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');`, or expecting the original string to change?

String functions don't modify the original string, they return the modified strings.

Comment: that's right. I think the op wants

    str = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');

Answer (score 5):

This worked, try pasting into the location box of your browser:

```
javascript:alert("item number:237728".replace(/[^0-9]/g,""))
```

As Neal says, I suspect your problem might be that of string mutability. Make sure you catch the return value from `replace()`.